# Why MongoDB does PROJECTION before filtering and sorting with simple find() query?

Tags: mongodb, projection, sql-execution-plan

Ok. I find it weird... but here's the deal.

For instance we have a collection with this schema `ageFrom`, `ageTo`, `price` and `enabled` properties of the documents. With indexes on 4 of them (it has much more properties in my case).

So... if i run

```
db.getCollection('product')
.find({
    "age_from": {"$gte": 36},
    "age_to": {"$lte": 36}
}, {"enabled":1}) // <-- here's the trick!
.sort({
    "price": 1
}).explain().queryPlanner.winningPlan
```

I get `PROJECTION` as the first stage, but if I remove `{"enabled": 1}` from projection the first stage would be SORT which is ok for me and works much faster.

So, why wouldn't MongoDB just get the documents and project then? Why does it have to modify them first?

Comment: but u r specifying `{"enabled":1}` , if u omit it , it won't project first, ain't that right ?

Comment: Yes. It won't project neither first nor anywhere else.